# Hibernate: How to delete a batch of object from subclass table when inheritanceType.joined is set?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, inheritance

I have two classes. One is Question, one is TempQuestion:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbQuestion")
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name="discriminator",
        discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Question {
    private Integer qstId;
    private String qstNum;
    private Integer versionNum;
    private String qstTitle;
    private String qstInstruction;
    private InterviewQstType qstType;
    private boolean isChildQuestion;
    private AnswerDataType answerDataType;
    private String chartNodeLocation;

    private Question parentQst;
    private Set<Question> childQsts;
    private Set<QstOption> options;
    private Set<Answer> answers;

    private List<QstOption> jumpTrgs;

.....
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tb_temp_question")
@DiscriminatorValue("temporary")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="qstId")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public class TempQuestion extends Question{

}
```

There is no any field only in TempQuestion (Just for testing purpose).
When I insert several records of data into these two tables, it works fine.
But When I try to delete all of them with the coding below, it gives me an error.

```
 @Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public void deleteAll{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String stringQuery = "DELETE FROM TempQuestion";
    Query query = session.createQuery(stringQuery);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

The log is as following:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    org.hibernate.hql.spi.TableBasedDeleteHandlerImpl.execute(TableBasedDeleteHandlerImpl.java:144)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.MultiTableDeleteExecutor.execute(MultiTableDeleteExecutor.java:61)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:445)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:379)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1286)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
    com.tong.tool.dao.impl.TempQuestionDaoImpl.deleteAll(TempQuestionDaoImpl.java:78)
    com.tong.tool.dao.impl.TempQuestionDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$80be7d2f.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    com.tong.tool.dao.impl.TempQuestionDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90817b69.deleteAll(<generated>)
    com.tong.tool.service.EditorService.deleteQuestions(EditorService.java:252)
    com.tong.tool.controller.QstEditorController.deleteQuestions(QstEditorController.java:141)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "ht_tb_temp_question" does not exist
  Position: 13
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    org.hibernate.hql.spi.TableBasedDeleteHandlerImpl.execute(TableBasedDeleteHandlerImpl.java:144)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.MultiTableDeleteExecutor.execute(MultiTableDeleteExecutor.java:61)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:445)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:379)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1286)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
    com.tong.tool.dao.impl.TempQuestionDaoImpl.deleteAll(TempQuestionDaoImpl.java:78)
    com.tong.tool.dao.impl.TempQuestionDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$80be7d2f.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    com.tong.tool.dao.impl.TempQuestionDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90817b69.deleteAll(<generated>)
    com.tong.tool.service.EditorService.deleteQuestions(EditorService.java:252)
    com.tong.tool.controller.QstEditorController.deleteQuestions(QstEditorController.java:141)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have searched for a long time, but I cannot find a correct answer for this. It seems not many people had this problem. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you hiding the deletion code from us?

Comment: This error is not Hibernate related but involves tables definition: when you use a joined strategy related tables (`tbQuestion` and `tb_temp_question`) should be joined with a relation; Hibernate, when no relation' name is specified, create a default name for it (ht_xxx) but you have to physically create it

Comment: Can you be more specific? How can I solve this problem? Or any link you I can read? I really cannot find the helpful resource. Thank you